# Need help with my rails 3 environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, environment

pulled down a repo from git.  For some reason I need to do

```
./script/rails.rb s
```

where on the rails 3 ap I started on my box, I can just do the

```
rails server
```

can anyone help me set up my environment so I don't have to do this?  I'm still trying to figure out what I need to type to do a migration...

Comment: can you provide a link to the repo?

Comment: Have you all bin from rubygems in your $PATH ?

Comment: can't provide a link to the repo... sorry, private.

Comment: -bash: /Users/john_t_krueger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin:/Users/john_t_krueger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/bin:/Users/john_t_krueger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin:/Users/john_t_krueger/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've figured this out.  The repo you downloaded was from somebody developing on a Windows machine.  They have to add the ".rb" extention to `script/rails` to get it to work right.

Calling `rails server` is really just an alias for `script/rails`.  But you're getting an error because when you type `rails server`, `script/rails` isn't there.

The solution is easy: in your local copy of that project, rename `script/rails.rb` back to `script/rails` the way it should be.

Also, `rails s` and `rails server` are the same thing - one is just a shortcut.

Comment: I don't even know how the file ended up as rails.rb!  It was definitely made on a mac.  I substituted the file with one from a rails 3 proj I had made on my box and it worked! thanks jaime.